# Change "href" with "img" tags in HTML code

Tags: html, joomla, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.0 and RSforms component there is a Directory view for form submissions. I have image field to upload image by user, when it comes to show submissions it shows just linked name of the image. Now I want to show the image itself.

The original code is like below :

```
<a href="/index.php/floor-2/floor-2-row-2/r18/r18-view?task=submissions.view.file&amp;hash=4bb4caf00d11d9efee04a4e196b69bce">5627585604f7e-3.jpg</a>
```

I changed it to show image itself :

```
<img src="/index.php/floor-2/floor-2-row-2/r18/r18-view?task=submissions.view.file&amp;hash=6b1d89f00383eb1644d421ed9fdd9eb8">
```

I know how to show image instead of link, but what I want to know is how to make it permanent and force RSforms to load all other fields like this,

Comment: Where is the image file and link?

Comment: <a href="/index.php/floor-2/floor-2-row-2/r18/r18-view?task=submissions.view.file&amp;hash=4bb4caf00d11d9efee04a4e196b69bce"><img src="5627585604f7e-3.jpg"></a>

Answer (score 0):

Image file and link are in my local wamp server,I found these codes with firebug,now I see other things,I found the source PHP code that generates this :

```
<?php foreach ($this->viewableFields as $field) { ?>
    <td align="center" class="center directoryCol directoryCol<?php echo $this->getFilteredName($field->FieldName); ?>"><?php echo $this->getValue($item, $field); ?></td>
```

this piece of code is generating all fields also image field . . .